# How to solve this differential equation (poisson process)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, poisson-process

Let $$g(x,t)=P(N_t=x)$$ where $$N_t $$ refers to the number of times a particular case occurs from 0 to t. (Poisson process)
$$\\$$
How to solve this differential equation below
$$\frac{d}{dt}\{e^{\lambda t} g(x,t)/\lambda^x\} = e^{\lambda t}g(x-1,t)/\lambda^{x-1}$$

given $$g(0,0)=1 ,\ \ \    g(1,0) = g(2,0)=...=0$$

Answer (score 2):

That's just the generator equation of the poisson process, so if you know the formula for a poisson random variable, then you have the explicit solution.

I'll assume that the point of the exercise is to assume that you **don't** know the explicit formula, and then derive it using that PDE as the starting point. Here's how to do that. Let $h(t,x) = e^{\lambda t} g(t,x)/\lambda^x$. The equation reads $$\partial_t h = Jh,$$ where $J$ is the linear operator given by $Jh(x):= h(x-1)$. This is just a linear equation in infinite variables so the solution at time $t$ will simply be given by $$h_t = e^{ t J} h_0.$$ Here $e^A:=\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{A^k}{k!}$ denotes the matrix exponential. On our case $A = tJ$ so that $A^nh(x) = t^n h(x-n)$. Thus $$h_t(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{ t^n}{n!}  h_0(x-n).$$In your case $h_0(y) = 1_{\{y=0\}}$, so that we simply get $h_t(x) = t^x/x!$ for $x \ge 0$. Thus $g(t,x) = \lambda^x e^{-\lambda t}h(t,x) = \lambda^xt^xe^{-\lambda t}/x!$, which is the correct formula for a Poisson variable.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do it without matrix exponentials by noting that $\partial_t h_t(0)=0$ so that $h_t(0)=1$, and then showing inductively that $h_t(x+1) = \int_0^t h_s(x)ds = \int_0^t (s^x/x!)ds = t^{x+1}/(x+1)!$.